# jquery click handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling, events, click

I create a bunch of  tags dynamically, appending them to a 
I then add a click handler...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ... code to append <a> tags to nav div        
    $("#nav a").click(function(event){ 
       alert('Clicked '+event.target.id);
       return false;
    });
});
```

If I have 10  tags as a result of this and click the first one, I get 10 (TEN!) alerts - but they all show the id of the tag I actually clicked.

(If I click the 5th tag, yep, I get 5 alerts - all with the 5th tag's id...)

What's going on here?
Is it because I dynamically created the tags?
Is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code that's being used to dynamically generate the anchors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* ... code to append <a> tags to nav div.  */      

    $("#nav a").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            console.log('Clicked ' + e.target.id);
            return false;   
        });
    });
});
```

However, these both are the same! There's no problem with your code. Check the tag generating code for bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I think you should check if your tags are being closed correctly. Use firebug to check the generated HTML. You'd might get this if your html looked like

```
<a>one<a>two<a>three</a></a></a>
```

Comment: That's a good thought! - but this raises another point...my code runs fine in IE and Chrome, but produces nothing in FF - no errors, nothing. Still, let me see what Firebug shows.

Comment: Well, you could probably chalk that up to browser differences... post here again if you HTML is fully correct...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ... code to append <a> tags to nav div        
    $("#nav a").click(function(event){ 
       alert('Clicked '+ this.id); // replaced with "this"
       return false;
    });
});
```

And make sure that your code is valid, eg:

```
<nav id="nav">
<a id="1" href="#"></a>
<a id="2" href="#"></a>
// ...
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

first use firebug to see if the id are actually placed correctly then i will change your code thos this and see if it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ... code to append <a> tags to nav div        
    $("#nav a").click(function(event){ 
       alert('Clicked '+ $(this).attr('id'));
       return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, at least it worked for me here in my test.

The problem can be IE6 weirdness or just a CSS problem with position:absolute; Display:block;

It seems to me NOT a javascript problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just as others have noticed, I think that there is something wrong with the code that you're using to dynamically generate the anchors.

Nonetheless, here's an example that *should* achieve the result you're aiming for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var eNav = document.getElementById('nav');

  var aLink = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    aLink = document.createElement('a');
    aLink.href = 'javascript:;';
    aLink.id = i;
    aLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Link'));
    eNav.appendChild(aLink);
  }

  $("#nav a").click(function(event){ 
    alert('Clicked '+ event.target.id);
    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your binding the event handler function `x` number of times to each element where `x` is the index of that element (+ 1) in the array/object properties over which you're iterating to do the binding.

How are you appending the `<a>` elements to the DOM? Can you show the complete relevant code?